# MapLibre - Trigger geolocation without zooming to location

Tags: javascript, maplibre-gl

Is there any way to start the `geolocate` service without the map zooming to the the geolocation position one the device has a position (as Google Maps does)?

Setting `fitBoundsOptions` to empty doesn't seem to help.